# Unable to loop through all nodes in a content type and load them without hitting memory limits

Tags: nodes, 8

I'm having an issue in Drupal 8 where I am unable to loop through a large amount of nodes without hitting memory limits. The *products* content type in the below example has ~6000 nodes. The memory limit is currently set to 512M and is not changeable.

I've tried unsetting the `$node` variable and clearing the entity cache  in the loop without any success.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
         ->condition('type', 'product')
         ->execute();
$nids = array_keys($query);

foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
    print $node->title->value;
}
```

The goal is to be able to iterate through all nodes of a content type without hitting memory limits.

Comment: And how did you clear the entity cache?

Comment: Why don't you use a queue or some cron process? Doing a long time and memory consuming process is not recommended even there's an admin user or automated request waiting (you know, people than *can* wait).

Comment: Clearing the cache with `\Drupal::entityManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->resetCache()`. Building a queue out seems a little extreme, this was possible in D7.

Comment: Try to use xhprof or a similar tool to figure out where the memory is actually used. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255941/tools-to-visually-analyze-memory-usage-of-a-php-app for some ways to do that. Could be a bug somewhere. There might be some services that are keeping references to the objects, blind guess would be entity type manager/typed data manager. You can kill them completely with \Drupal::getContainer->set('service_id', NULL).

Comment: No luck, tried where 'service_id' was 'entity.manager'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using the following command pulled from the deprecated `node_load()` function.

`\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache(array('NID'));`

The fixed script would be:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
         ->condition('type', 'product')
         ->execute();
$nids = array_keys($query);

foreach ($nids as $nid) {
    $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
    print $node->title->value;
    \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache(array($nid));
}
```